# How to create a "Percentage of Success" field in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

In TABLEAU, I'm looking at creating a field that calculates the percentage of success of certain types of kickstarter campaigns.

I've tried using the calculated fields option to no avail.

[Present in the dataset is a status dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOXHv.png)

I'm looking to have a simple formula like SUM([Status]= Successful)/ SUM(([Status]= Successful)+([Status]= Failed)) *100

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth looking at this: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_percentages_options.htm

In this case though you should be able wrap your divisor in a `total()` in order to get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

IF all you are looking for is the % of success you can use a calculation:

```
Success = SUM(IIF(Status="successful",1,0))/Count(Status)
```

This should give the % of success. Hope this helps.